# New Yorker story about a race of giant companions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This might have run in the *New Yorker* in the 1990s or early 2000s. The human protagonists had companions, confidants, who were giant (10 feet tall) and supposedly stupid, simple, and infantile. The humans treated the giants like Scarlett treated Mammy (in my opinion), as cherished comforters and advice-givers, but clearly subservient and considered inferior.

Really it was the humans who were inferior, behaving like infants in public, squabbling and bursting into tears at the slightest perceived offense. The humans took their companions with them everywhere, wanting to be held, cuddled, and carried like infants when a social situation with other humans became even slightly uncomfortable.

At social functions, there were refreshments tables specifically for the companions, stocked with non-alcoholic sweet drinks, because the companions were assumed to prefer sweet things. They were assumed to be sexless as well.

In the reveal, the companions are shown to secretly have utter contempt for their human masters. They hated sweet drinks, enjoyed alcohol and sex, and when they could get away with it, would drink and smoke cigarettes and fornicate without their masters’ knowledge.

I did ask this question several years ago on a general-interest message board, and we ruled out: "Softies" by Stan Nichols; "Gun, With Occasional Music" by Jonathan Lethem; and "The Mount" by Carol Emshwiller. And another detail: this is a story about urban, affluent, mostly white people, almost certainly some sort of alt-universe New Yorkers.

Comment: Just to rule out a possibility, it's probably not "[Los Gigantes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124042436/https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2012/02/06/los-gigantes)" by T. Corghassen Boyle, which was published in The New-Yorker..

Comment: Thanks, but it's not "Los Gigantes."

Comment: This is ringing a vague bell. If it is the story I remember then the "companions" have some form of telepathic communication and they chat (and arrange assignations) mentally while shepherding their humans. But my memory of this predates the 2000s.

Comment: That doesn't sound incompatible, and the story might well be pre-2000s. Another detail I realized was when two giants do it sexually, if they're in a human-sized room it's almost too small, and they have to brace themselves against opposite walls. Kind of graphic, sorry, but it was in the story.